# Building web app on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu-14.04, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add a sqlite db to my ubuntu server following this tutorial:

> http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/coreclr/getting-started-linux.html#install-sqlite

but I'm come across an error on the

> To make sure the files are correct, you can compile the project on the command line by running dnu build --quiet

part.

After running the command (dnu build --quiet) I get the following errors:

```
    Building KeepItSolved for DNXCore,Version=v5.0
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/var/www/kis/src/KeepItSolved/bin/Debug/dnxcore50' is denied.
   at System.IO.UnixFileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.RoslynProjectReference.EmitAssembly(String outputPath)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.BuildContext.Build(List`1 diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.BuildManager.BuildConfiguration(String baseOutputPath, IEnumerable`1 frameworks, List`1 allDiagnostics, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.BuildManager.BuildInternal(String projectPath)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.BuildManager.Build()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.BuildConsoleCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Register>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
```

I tried accessing

> '/var/www/kis/src/KeepItSolved/bin/Debug/dnxcore50'

but it doesn't exist (neither on my server, nor my local machine. Everything builds fine on my local though). Here's a link to my repository: https://github.com/ziombo/KeepItSolved/

Comment: Do you have to `sudo` the build command? Also, is this your production server? It's not recommended to build on it. You should publish on a different machine and them copy the binaries there

Comment: No sudo "sudo: dnu: command not found". I'm not really sure what kind of server it is. Currently I'm just trying to make my web app publicly accessible. I'm doing exactly what I'm told in the tutorial, so since one of the steps is giving me an error I don't want to move further.

Comment: Sounds like your sudo command is configured to give a different path, see [here](http://superuser.com/a/709522/369336)

Comment: But it looks like you are compiling your app directly in the `/var/www` folder, It's probably better to do it in a subfolder of your home directory where you do have full control and then copy (i.e. deploy) it to `/var/www`

Comment: David, Your solution about sudo command being configured to give a different path worked! I suggest You add this as a formal answer so I can accept it.